# How can I allow for three integers to be entered followed by a space and a word before the system checks for exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

This is a homework assignment and I apologize for the dumb question I just can't seem to crack it and I have tried a few ways, including `.hasInt();`. The code I have works for checking if the user is entering integers buy won't allow anything after I want to allow the user to enter `"5 hours, 10 minutes, 15 seconds."`. So far I can only allow them to enter `"5 10 15"` and anything else gets caught by the exception and asks him to enter valid numbers. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TimetoSeconds
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Time converter");
    System.out.println();
    //start scanner and variables
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 60;
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        //catch exceptions
        int hours = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int seconds = 0;
        try
        {
        // get user input
        System.out.print("Enter time in hours (space), minutes (space), and
                    seconds:  ");
        hours = sc.nextInt();
        minutes = sc.nextInt();
        seconds = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Error! Invalid number. Try again.\n");
            continue;
        }

        int sec1 = (hours * x) * x;
        int sec2 = minutes * x;
        int totalSec = sec1 + sec2 + seconds;

        System.out.print("Total seconds are:  " + totalSec + "\n");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n):   ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is your question den?

Comment: The thing to remember is that numbers are integers, and words are strings.  If you tell it you want to accept integers, you'll get only them.  You need to accept a string and parse it.

Comment: Have you learned about Regular Expressions yet?

Comment: Please give some information about what exactly is your question. What d o you want to allow the user and what not? Should he be able to enter "10 minutes"? Should that only filter out the "10" or should it also calculate for example the seconds of it?

Comment: It should calculate all the integer and omit the words. So, yes it should only filter out the words. And no I have not learned about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this part.

```
    System.out.print("Enter time in hours (space), minutes (space), and seconds:  ");
    hours = sc.nextInt();
    sc.next();
    minutes = sc.nextInt();
    sc.next();
    seconds = sc.nextInt();
    sc.next();
```

Then your program works OK.

```
Time converter

Enter time in hours (space), minutes (space), and seconds:  5 hours, 10 minutes, 12 seconds

Total seconds are:  18612

Continue? (y/n):   y

Enter time in hours (space), minutes (space), and seconds:  3 hours, 10 minutes, 20 seconds

Total seconds are:  11420

Continue? (y/n):   n
```

But this is kind of error-prone. I would rather read the whole big string
which the user enters e.g. "5 hours, 10 minutes, 20 seconds" and then
extract whatever I need from there (and I would need just the 3 numbers).
What is it error-prone? Because if the user types "5 hours , 10 minutes , 20 seconds",
it will still detect this as invalid input (as the commas are not glued to the words).

Comment: Okay yes, it is working perfectly. so the concept I guess is that it is omitting any other string after the number right? But how is it still error-prone? Im not quite sure I get that explanation.

Comment: It is omitting 1 string in between each number. It is error prone because the user may type two strings there as I showed with the commas.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in the entire string using `nextLine` and then get the numbers with `split`:

```
    System.out.print("Enter time in hours (space), minutes (space), and seconds:  "); 
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String values[] = line.trim().split("[^0-9]+");
```

The argument to `split` is a regular expression; it treats any sequence of one or more *non*-digits as a delimiter, and returns the substrings between the delimiters.  Thus, all elements of `values[]` will be strings with just digits (except that `values[0]` could be an empty string), and you can use `Integer.parseInt` to get the actual integers.  You can also easily check to make sure they've entered the correct number of integers.  `trim()` just gets rid of leading and trailing spaces, so that if they enter `"  5 10 15"`, it will still work.  (But if they enter `" give me 5, 10, 15"`, `values[0]` will be `""`, and `values[1]` will be `"5"`, etc.)  This solution won't let the user enter numbers on separate lines, the way using Scanner's `nextInt` would.  If the ability to enter on separate lines is necessary, the above solution won't work without using a loop and some extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `StringTokenizer`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is the link to the stringtokenizer in the java api.

It allows you to define the delimiters and get the substrings that these delimiters split.